# Udbuntu Pycharm does not let me paste my code

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, copy-paste, paste

I am trying to copy some code which is saved as a .py cript from pycharm on windows into pycharm in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS which I am running on Hyper-V. I tried every possible shortcut and tried IdeaVim but can not seem to find the Vim Emulator since I read that could fix the issue.
There must be a way to just copy and paste my code since I am not looking forward to copying evry single line of code by hand.

I am just lost on this one and how to do this simple task of pasting my code into pycharm Ubuntu